# why does "gem install rails" results in an error "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just tried to downgrade my ruby on rails environment from 1.9.3 to 1.8.7

I have successfully updated Ruby!  However I am now trying to update "rails".

when I run, I get the following error.  How do I fix this?

```
$ gem install rails 
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

thanks

IF I run $ gem install rails --debug I get the following:

```
Exception `Gem::LoadError' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:298 - Could n
Exception `LoadError' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 -
Exception `LoadError' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:141 -
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - The system can
Exception `Win32::Registry::Error' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:397 - No more data i
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 - File exists - c:/Users/Adam/
Exception `Resolv::DNS::Config::NXDomain' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/resolv.rb:495 - _rubygems._tcp.
Exception `Resolv::DNS::Config::NXDomain' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/resolv.rb:495 - _rubygems._tcp.
Exception `Resolv::ResolvError' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/resolv.rb:459 - DNS result has no informa
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 - File exists - c:/Ruby187/lib
Exception `Gem::InstallError' at c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:543 - activ
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

Comment: How did you successfully update ruby??

Comment: Use  .ruby-version file to manage the ruby version. That way, it will ask you to install new ruby version if it has not been installed yet, and then when you run bundle install will install gem for that specific ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3."

But you just said you downgraded your version of ruby to 1.8.7.
Surely you need to update ruby back to your original version of 1.9.3 to update rails.

Also listed on http://ubyonrails.org/download :-

> "We recommend Ruby 2.1.0 for use with Rails. We stopped supporting
>   Ruby 1.8.x after Rails 3.2. Ruby 1.9.2+ will be supported until Rails
>   5."

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby 1.8.7 is no longer supported.](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/), its highly discouraged to use 1.8.7 as you won't receive any security updates.

As a result, latest stable version of rails - v4.1 requires ruby 1.9.3 or higher. if for some reason, you still want to use old, out-dated & unsupported version of ruby. you have to use a older version of rails:

```
$ gem install rails -v 3.2
```

But I would encourage you to upgrade to latest ruby 2.1.2 as its MUCH MUCH faster & better.

Comment: Was just going to point him at rails version, ah well two fingered typist loses again...

Comment: two finger typing, really? if yes, then I guess you using the right language. try doing java with two fingered typing :P

Comment: That's what intellisense and good naming conventions are for. :)

Comment: I know its outdated - but Im trying to work with my hosting service...  thanks trying this now!

Comment: That's such a crappy host. use a better hosting like Heroku(free) or digital ocean($5/mo).